# Algebra Linear 2-norm

Tags: linear-algebra

If $Q_1 \space and\space Q_2$ are orthogonal show that $||A||_2=||Q_1AQ_2||_2$. What I did is $$||Q_1AQ_2||_2=tr((Q_1AQ_2)^t(Q_1AQ_2))=tr(Q_2^tA^tQ_1^tQ_1AQ_2)=tr(Q_2^tA^tAQ_2)$$
How can I make now?
$Q^t$ represents transposed, and tr represents trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $tr(BC) = tr(CB)$ in general (I'm assuming your matrices are square). Apply this to $B = Q_2^t, C = A^t A Q_2$ to get your last expression to be just $tr(A^tA)$.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think I could do this change

Comment: Time to review the theorems on trace and det, I'd guess. By the way, you *cannot* do $tr(ABC) = tr(BAC)$, even though you might think you could. It's worth finding a counterexample to convince yourself of this.